# ajax query not waiting for first ajax query to execute -- I think

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have two ajax queries. In the first one, I enter a new record showing an artwork and the user's rating and comment on it. In the second one, I look at the all the records, determine the number of responses for each distinct artist and the average rate, and show those numbers on the webpage.

The trouble is, when a new record is entered, the on-page feedback doesn't always recognize that the new record has been entered. If you refresh the page, the number of user responses will increase by 1 and the new average will be reflected. So I think there's something amiss with the way I'm handling the asynchronous aspect of jquery.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```js
//code about that gets the user's answers from a form
//then the code below

function ajax1() { //put in database
  $.ajax({
    url: "php/newComment.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: ({
      'artwork': artwork,
      'ip': ip,
      'timestamp': timestamp,
      'rank': rank,
      'comment': comment
    }),
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {}
  });
} //all good here; it works

$.when(ajax1()).done(function() {
  $.ajax({ //fetch the number of responses 
    //and average data from dB
    url: "php/get-averages-number.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: ({
      'artwork': artwork
    }),
    success: function(data) {
      var objArt = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      for (i = 0; i < objArt.length; i++) {
        if (artwork == objArt[i].artwork) {
          $('#' + artwork + '-respondents').text(objArt[i].num + " respondent(s) so far");
          var score = parseFloat(objArt[i].avg);
          var rounded = Math.round(score * 10) / 10;
          $('#' + artwork + '-average').text(rounded.toFixed(1) + " average score");
        }
      }
    },
    error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {}
  }); //this works, but doesn't always reflect that
  //a new response was just entered
});
```

Comment: The `ajax1()` function doesn't return a promise (or indeed, anything at all) so the `.done()` is fired immediately. Make the function `return $.ajax({...`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Could you spell out your suggestion more fully please? I'm a little new to this idea.

Comment: You need to return the jqXHR object from the `$.ajax` call in `ajax1()` function to the `$.when()` call. To do that simply add the word `return` to the start of your function.

Comment: I added an answer for you below which shows the exact code, but the only thing you need to do is to add the `return` keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your `ajax1()` function is not returning a promise (or indeed, anything at all) so `done()` fires immediately.

To fix this, return the jqXHR object from `$.ajax()` in `ajax1()` to the `$.when()` call by adding the `return` keyword:

```
function ajax1() { 
  return $.ajax({ // add return here
    // ajax settings...
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! So the first function must return a value before the second function can fire.

Comment: It's not quite as broad as that, it's simply that for `$.when()` to wait for an async process you have to pass it a reference to that async process. Your original logic did not do that